# How can I identify if an entry in List 1 is also in List 2 in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have two sets of data, List 1 on Sheet 1, List 2 on Sheet 2, of the same LibreOffice Calc workbook.

Everything in List 1 exists in List 2 which also contains additional items that are not in List 1.

In List 2 I want to be able to identify items that are in List 1 by inserting 1 (one) in an adjacent column, and for those items in List 2 that are not in List 1 inserting a 0 (zero). I will then use the 1s and 0s as multipliers in other operations.

Comment: What is the question here exactly? Could you please provide us with some code you started working on?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function MATCH(SearchCriterion; LookupArray; Type) to find the position of an item (SearchCriterion) in an array (LookupArray). Assuming the list is not sorted, use Type 0.

If the item is not found, MATCH returns #N/A, so check the result with IF(ISNA(...;0;1)).

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(item;list;0));0;1)
```

[image]

Comment: Tried this, but all rows return N/A, despite the fact that it looks as if some of the content is common to both lists. Maybe there's some formatting that's not apparent to me that prevents an exact Match.

Comment: Formatting could be an issue. If you have text, there might be trailing spaces in one of the list; they would be included as well.  I have also added an image for details.

Comment: Typo at the mentioned text `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(item;list;0);0;1))`. According to the image parenthesis should be like `=IF(ISNA(MATCH(item;list;0));0;1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. This worked when I retyped some of the list items, so clearly there is a hidden formatting issue. Hopefully I can get around this by pasting **scraped** data into Text Editor then copying and pasting into Calc from there, hopefully losing all spurious formatting along the way.

Comment: Was able to remove spurious spaces using TRIM function in both lists, then =IF(ISNA(MATCH(item;list;0);0;1)) did exactly what I wanted.